# How to void value looping many time in foreach loop (echo one time)

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have problem with foreach loop. I need to echo "Gunindu" this value at one time but it's looping more times. How do I Stop it?

[image]

Comment: use  `array_unique($data);` and also read manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: If these are results from a DB, then it's a case of formatting your output. They are not duplicates as the "tasks" are different.

Comment: task are different,but when i get data from DB their have issue.their duplicate NAME 3 times,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before foreeach loop use `array_unique()` function for remove duplicate data

for Example

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Reference [PHP Manual][1]
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php